# Loading image from firebase storage not loading image using glide using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am trying to load an image from Firebase Storage using Kotlin and Glide. i added all the dependecies and apply plugin:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

My code is as follows:

```
val storageRef = Firebase.storage.reference

    val imageref = storageRef.child("test/test.jpg")

    imagetest = findViewById(R.id.imageView5)

    Glide.with(this)
        .load(imageref)
        .into(imagetest)
```

When running the code, the imageview which had a default image goes black indicating that the code is trying to retrieve something from Firebase Storage. but the imageView never populates the downloaded image. assuming the download actually happens.

Am I doing something wrong? my firebase Storage screenshot is below:

[image]

I have tested this a little bit more, and Glide seems to load images from HTTPS ok, regardless of where i pull the URL from. But cloud storage provide URL as GS://. so how do i convert the GS:// to HTTPS://?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Figured it out.

```
imageref = Firebase.storage.reference.child("test/test.jpg")
    imageref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {Uri->

        val imageURL = Uri.toString()
        imagetest = findViewById(R.id.imageView5)


        Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageURL)
            .into(imagetest)

    }
```

the 'downloadurl' statement actually converts the GS:// to HTTPS://

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the both:

**GS URL:**

```
gs://<your_project_id>.appspot.com/test/test.jpg
```

**HTPPS URL:**

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/<your_project_id>.appspot.com/o/test%2Ftest.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process where my problem fixed -

Step 1 - go to build.gradle(app) and add these dependency

```xml
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.x.x'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.x.x'
```

Step 2 -
Create a java file

```java
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

Step 3 - Set image where you want

```java
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<your-app>/").child("folder"); //add .child(nested_folder) if nested folder occurs
GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(storageRef.child(test_image.jpg))
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
//that .load() will be load like .load(gs://<your_app/folder/test_image.jpg>)
```